# Encrypted automounting partition

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, disk-encryption

I have a debian based server at home using banana-pro. One of its functions is being a backup/owncloud/nas. There is a sata drive attached to it and I want it to be encrypted. I know that for a pc I could use truecrypt. I'd like this drive to automount and unencrypt on bootup with server. It would be also really nice if I could plug it into another computer and access the files on it with a password. Is something like this easily doable?

Comment: If you want automount on bootup that means the key needs to be present without human interaction. So what's the point of the encryption if the key is present anyway? The defeats the purpose.

Comment: Not that much. If somebody gets access to the server, he will be able to access the data, but if he gets only hdd he won't be able to do a thing.

Comment: I agree with Marco. The point of having a server encrypted with encryption keys on it is flawed.

Comment: But what else can I do? If I won't have the encryption keys on server I will have to unencrypt it every time I restart the sever. Is there a smarter way of doing it?

Comment: There is a point to having an encrypted disk with the key present on the server. If nothing else, it makes it easy to revoke access (scrub the key out of `/boot` or wherever). Or you could put the key on a USB stick and leave it plugged in; then you can take the USB stick away whenever you want real security.

Comment: IMO this doesn't add much to security. If someone can steal the HDD he/she has physical access. And granted this access he/she also has access to the key. Very little security benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encrypt a disk, you would want to use LUKS.

I will leave you the relevant page:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/

Comment: Thanks. Will I be able to access this drive later on with another OS'es? Prefferably Mac and maybe Windows?

Comment: Last time I check, in OS/X only within a Linux VM. No idea about support for Windows.